# ScriptingOptions.BatchSize has no effect

Tags: sql-server, smo

I am trying to script data for all tables in database using SMO Transfer Class. I am trying to create batches of INSERT statements. The ScriptingOptions property BatchSize seems to be ignored here as my final script contains Batch Separator "GO" after each INSERT statement. Below is code snippet I am using:

```
so.BatchSize = 500;
so.ScriptBatchTerminator = true;
so.NoCommandTerminator = false;
so.ScriptData = true;
so.SchemaQualify = true;
//and few other options all set to false

...

Transfer tData = new Transfer(sourceDb);
tData.Options = so;

...

tData.CopySchema = true;
tData.CopyData = true;

...

tData.EnumScriptTransfer();
```

The output script is like this:

```
INSERT INTO...
GO
INSERT INTO...
GO
INSERT INTO...
GO
...
```

but the expected output is

```
INSERT INTO...
INSERT INTO...
INSERT INTO...
//497 more INSERTS
GO
...
```

Comment: Transfer.BatchSize is not available as I am using 2008 assemblies.

Comment: I switched to 2012 assemblies and tried using Transfer.BatchSize. The issue here is it always inserts GO after 100 rows, regardless of the value specified for this property.

Answer (score 0):

The SqlBulkCopy class also has a BatchSize and BulkCopyTimeout. My guess is that since you are outputting to plain text instead of running TransferData(), the scripter is doing it's own thing. When running TransferData() on the Transfer object, monitoring the progress with Activity Monitor in SMMS, you can see it is performing an INSERT BULK instead of many small inserts.